# Extract data from curve fit toolbox

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab and I have a certain set of x and y data,

```
x=[0,1.25,1.88,2.5,5,6.25,6.88,7.19,7.5,10,12.5,15,20];
y=[-85.93,-78.82,-56.95,-34.56,-33.57,-39.64,-41.96,-49.28,-66.6,-66.61,-59.16,-48.78,-41.53];
```

I want to use the curve fitting toolbox which has the spline function to generate a graph, so i did this,

```
cftool
```

It would bring me to the toolbox which i can then choose the spline fit. I was thinking if its possible that i extract the data points from the spline graph generated. Which means i probably would have more x and y data points than those that i input in, since the spline graph is sort of a continuous graph. Anyone could give me some advice on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the equivalent of the spline fit performed with `cftool` with `fit`, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734071/matlab-curve-fit-display-equation-on-graph/18735131#18735131), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575126/curve-fitting-in-matlab-different-result-form-toolbox-vs-command-line?rq=1), or here:

```
% perform spline fit without cftool
ft = fittype('cubicspline');
coeff=fit(x,y,ft); 

% use plot to display the interpolating polynomial 
% (relying on internal plot settings)
figure
h=plot(coeff,x,y,'o');

% extract the *interpolated* curve from the figure
xi=get(h,'XData');
yi=get(h,'YData');
```

Replot it just to show that we can:

[image]

But if you just want to interpolate do as Fraukje explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735391/extracting-data-points-from-a-plot-on-a-finer-scale?rq=1). Define a finer grid on `x` and use the `interp1` function, as in the following example (same x,y input data as before):

```
% interpolate 
Ni = 100;
xi = linspace(x(1),x(end),Ni);
yi = interp1(x,y,xi,'spline');
```

Now `xi,yi` is the interpolated data:

[image]

Comment: i think interpolating is not as accurate as it should be.so i was hoping to get the data straight from the spline fit graph.is that possible?

Comment: @BenjaminAlonsoTan the first part of the answer explains one way: `xi=get(h,'XData'); ...` (if you perform the fits as shown in my answer). Also look at the answers I link to...

Comment: @BenjaminAlonsoTan I don't really see a *big* difference (graphically) in the results of the two approaches.